# How to add machine code at the end of an executable file on Windows(PE) or Linux(ELF)?

Tags: binary, elf, portable-executable, machine-code

### **Detail**

I know that it is possible to add code in the famous 'code caves', but they are limited in terms of space, so I would like to add codes in this file without using these spaces, and for that I would have to add extra bytes to the file (at the end so that jmps and memory access are not affected).

But I can't find any application that allows me to do this, I have `cutter` and `x96dbg` and they only allow changing existing bytes.

### **Main**

**So I would like to know which tool I can use to do what I want, if it is possible to do what I want.**

### **Secondary**

Note: From what I've been researching, changing the size of a binary by adding extra codes to it causes a series of complications, because if added at the beginning, it ruins all the jmps and the read sections and the read/write sections. If that's the reason for not adding extra codes (with new bytes), why wouldn't adding the code at the end of the binary be a solution? And how exactly does one section that can only read and one that can read and write work? Essentially, they are all editable bytes that can be read and written, right?

Comment: Doing this will invalidate the code signing certificate so many apps will refuse to run.  You can append to the end of a file but by itself that does not make it part of the executable -- self-extracting archives work that way:  (self-extractor applet)  + (possibly a marker string) + (archive).  I don't know enough about the PE format to know if you can append to the end (or where the signing cert was) and then modify earlier data to make it part of the executed code.

Comment: What's the plan to execute the added machine code?  The program won't know about it, and there's nothing natural to binaries that will make all the code execute.

Comment: Erik Edit In that case in the middle of the program code I would add a jmp or something to the new area of the added memory, and a jmp to return to the point before.

Comment: Why not just insert all your code at that middle?  Or maybe take over the program entry point..

Comment: Erik Eidt thinks like this, the compiled code is 1mb in size and for some strange reason I have to put 2mb of code in this executable. This is a silly example and I know I can put this code in a DLL (On Windows) and call it in the middle of the executable. But I really wanted to understand the WHY it is not possible to add codes in new bytes in a file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ELF binaries, you could simply append whatever bytes you want to the end of the file.

However, the appended data will *not* be loaded into memory. To get this data loaded, you would have to modify one of the executable segments in your binary to "cover" the newly-added data. You can see the segments using `readelf -Wl a.out`.

If you are lucky and the executable `LOAD` segment can be modified the cover the new data, then patching the main `.text` to jump to the new executable code and then jumping back will work.

P.S.

> I can't find any application that allows me to do this

Stackoverflow is not the place to ask for applications.

Comment: So the problem with adding extra code is that you'll need to change the segment sizes... that makes sense